# Dynamic Where Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using `System.Linq.Dynamic` to make dinanmico where in my research. In the code below I try to filter by `Funcao`, but returns the error:

`No property or field 'Funcao' exists in type 'ASO'`

How do I filter by an alias of my Linq?

#### CODE

```
public static ResultadoListagemPadrao Grid(int iniciarNoRegistro, int qtdeRegistro, string orderna, string ordenaTipo, string filtro, int filtroID, UsuarioLogado usuarioLogado)
{
    var where = "";
    var id = 0;

    if (filtroID > 0)
        where += " FuncionarioID == " + filtroID.ToString();
    else
    {
        if (int.TryParse(filtro, out id))
            where += " ASOID == " + id.ToString();
        if (filtro != null)
            where += " Funcao.Contains(@0) "; 
    }
    using (var db = new ERPContext())
    {
        var resultado = new ResultadoListagemPadrao();
        resultado.TotalRegistros = db.ASO.Total(usuarioLogado.EmpresaIDLogada);
        resultado.TotalRegistrosVisualizados = db.ASO.ToListERP(usuarioLogado.EmpresaIDLogada).AsQueryable().Where(where, filtro).Count();

        resultado.Dados =
            (from a in db.ASO.ToListERP(usuarioLogado.EmpresaIDLogada).AsQueryable()
                select new
                {
                    a.ASOID,
                    a.FuncionarioID,
                    Cliente = a.Funcionario.Cliente.Pessoa.Nome,
                    Setor = a.FuncionarioFuncao.Funcao.Setor.Descricao,
                    Funcao = a.FuncionarioFuncao.Funcao.Descricao,
                    Funcionario = a.Funcionario.Pessoa.Nome,
                    a.DtASO,
                    a.Status                         
                })
            .Where(where, filtro)
            .OrderBy(orderna + " " + ordenaTipo)
            .Skip(iniciarNoRegistro)
            .Take(qtdeRegistro)
            .ToArray();

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Comment: For this specific problem, I don't see a need to use Dynamic-LINQ, regular LINQ should work.  You can chain your `Where` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is this line `db.ASO.ToListERP(usuarioLogado.EmpresaIDLogada).AsQueryable().Where(where, filtro)`

Your class `ASO` doesn't have a property `Funcao`.

Try remove the `Where` on that line. Try this...

```
        var resultado = new ResultadoListagemPadrao();
        resultado.TotalRegistros = db.ASO.Total(usuarioLogado.EmpresaIDLogada);
        var query = (from a in db.ASO.ToListERP(usuarioLogado.EmpresaIDLogada).AsQueryable()
                select new
                {
                    a.ASOID,
                    a.FuncionarioID,
                    Cliente = a.Funcionario.Cliente.Pessoa.Nome,
                    Setor = a.FuncionarioFuncao.Funcao.Setor.Descricao,
                    Funcao = a.FuncionarioFuncao.Funcao.Descricao,
                    Funcionario = a.Funcionario.Pessoa.Nome,
                    a.DtASO,
                    a.Status                         
                })
            .Where(where, filtro);
        resultado.TotalRegistrosVisualizados = query.Count();    
        resultado.Dados = query 
            .OrderBy(orderna + " " + ordenaTipo)
            .Skip(iniciarNoRegistro)
            .Take(qtdeRegistro)
            .ToArray();

        return resultado;
```

Please in future translate your code.